# Why is my question getting close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

I have already got 3 close votes for the question "Which is the standard method of Email Verification?" that I have posted on Stack Overflow. The reason shown for the close votes is "primarily opinion-based". But my question hasn't got even a single down vote.

Here is the link to my question: [Which is the standard method of Email Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990667/which-is-the-standard-method-of-email-verification)

I have clearly stated in my question body that I am looking for the universally approved standard method for email verification. I have even posted the technique that I follow correctly so that others can guide me if there is any mistake with my current technique. I have read the terms and guidelines to ask questions on Stack Overflow many times. I still can't find what is wrong with my question and how I broke the standard of asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Great new fellas. My question has been closed, within the time that I typed here. 
"put on hold as primarily opinion-based by Elias Van Ootegem, Maerlyn, Raul Rene, DaImTo, legoscia 1 min ago"

Hope the experts here can tell me the issue with my question so that I can avoid the mistake next time.

Comment: Your question was closed as primarily opinion-based because there is no "standard method" to verify emails.

Comment: :O Then the time has already been exceeded to make one. Email verification is one of the most commonly used features in web applications with user session (registration, accounts and all). Security is really important too for it.

Comment: Here is the link to a question posted by one of the guys who voted to close my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586435/emulator-or-not-to-emulator  Now tell whose question is primarily opinion based??? And why it isn't closed yet?

Comment: @AeJey: sure, but the way your question is phrased will lead to primarily opinion-based answers. What research have you done yourself? What were your findings? Can you narrow this down to, say, a conflicting view between two articles on the subject you found? Have you looked at Security.SE to see if they have answers? Sharing your research helps everyone *and* helps narrow the focus.

Comment: @AeJey: And Stack Overflow gets *thousands* of new questions every day. This means that some off-topic questions linger longer, slip through the net. Don't use other questions that are still open as a jardstick.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you Martin. I just pointed out the "hand less man laughing at a man without index finger" action by a member in SO. Most of his posts are clearly opinion based and he voted to close my post saying that my question is opinion based. :P

Comment: @AeJey: Perhaps that user has learned more about what Stack Overflow is about? There were *5* voters, no need to start attacking individual voters here. I would have voted the same.

Comment: I will post a new question including all the details of my researches and my current technique for email verification and the security issues my current techniques and the other methods I know and all soon. But I still doubt how I can learn which one is the best technique. Will that become opinion based again? :(

Comment: There is no "best" technique in general. There are techniques more appropriate to some situations, and others to other situations. You would be better off describing the problem you're facing with what you're currently using. If someone knows of a better technique _for your situation_, they can answer with that (and an explanation of why it is better).

Comment: @AeJey **do not** post a new question. Edit the question you have. That will automatically queue it for re-opening. Leaving your old question in a bad state will hurt the site and deleting it could lead you to a question ban. Edit, always edit.

Comment: @KateGregory My personal experience is that the questions will remain closed even when they should be reopened.. Proof? I did that with a couple of questions of mine that got closed. They remained closed for weeks after an edit. Before you say, the edits weren't good, when I deleted and asked again, not only did it not get closed, but got a couple of upvotes too..

Comment: @Pat people who don't care about the norms of the site may find themselves unable to use the site. Deleting and asking again is rude and can lead to a ban, especially if the deleted question was heavily downvoted.

Comment: @KateGregory I actually do agree with you Kate.. Really bad questions will be closed again even if deleted and reposted, and indeed that is something to avoid. But the current reopening system is broken, at least to some degree, from what I've experienced. (Yes, I know my personal experience doesn't account for much, but I've heard similar complaints from others too.. Though I do not know the extent..)

Answer (score 12):

**Stack Overflow prefers questions that have a definitive and verifiable answer.**

Discussion, one-of-many, or open-ended questions are usually a bad fit for this format and openly discouraged, although there are a few in the archives from several years ago.

### Always read the hold message

I'm sure you saw this:

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based by Elias Van Ootegem, Maerlyn,
>   Raul Rene, DaImTo, legoscia 20 hours ago
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the
>   help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.

Let's look at this first:

The question is put on hold, suspending answers but not comments.  It is still there.  It can still eventually get reopened and answered if you make edits, or even if never answered some of the comments or links people send could be useful.

It shows which users put it on hold.  A question is usually put on hold by 5 users who have enough points to have earned the privilege to vote on posts in this way, to help create or influence site standards.

It asks you to **rephrase your question so that it is not an opinion question**.

#### You can ask here, or ask the voters

One thing you can do, though it doesn't always work, is to message a single voting user about this by putting @ in from of their name in comments or an appropriate chat room, and *politely* ask like this:

@someone What could I do to ask a better question?

Just keep in mind that the voters are volunteers and fellow site visitors just like you and equally busy or perhaps more so (and certainly not employees that you or Stack Exchange Inc. has paid to answer).  The answer to a direct message could sometimes be something like "that is off topic here" or "read the help and edit your question" This is not to be rude, though it seems that way when trying to get something answered.  Often, though, people will offer helpful hints.

### Why this is an opinion question

I can guess why a question like this might be closed, but I don't know why these 5 users wanted it closed.  So what I have to say next may or may not be useful.

#### Is "Which is the standard method of email verification?" an "opinion" question?

**Yes.**

**"Which?" implies a one-of-many choice**.   And **"standard" often subjectively means "best"**.

If you have used a bunch of different internet sites, you will know that even on high value e-commerce sites, like banks, paypal, and stock brokers, there is some variation in how they do email verification and lost password from the variations in the emails received and the questions asked in the user interfaces.  Not a lot, but there is some.  So it would appear, there is not a single standard.

Since there is not a single standard, you are asking an opinion.

#### Other strong potential reasons for a "on hold" vote

These may not strictly apply to the question that was asked, but are mentioned to help avoid common issues that often occur with similar questions from new users.

- "Questions asking us to find a favorite tool, library, or off site resource are off-topic...".  That could happen for asking for a PHP library to do email validation.
- "Unclear what you are asking".   "Which is the standard method of Email Verification?" is a little unclear because the title suggests we are going to see at least 2 ways of doing something, or be asked about a best way, but the body asks about a single example of specific code.  Be careful that the title reflects what is asked in the body. If the problem is just in the title, the title should be edited by you, or anyone else, to better match the body.
- "Duplicate of ..."  This doesn't mean exact duplicates.  It means that the issue the OP has is answered already and there isn't really anything "new" in the new question.

  - Search before asking.  There are [152 previous questions and answers for the search "[php][mysql] email validation"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+email+verification)

    - When searching, you might have to think about how the other question and answer pertains to your situation, change variable names, or "run the code in your head" and that is effort and includes a possibility of error. The upside is you can get an answer this way without waiting.
    - We all want human interaction and personalization to our specific concerns, but SO isn't always the best place to seek that.
  - A pretty good duplicate for your general question (from the title) is [Easiest way for PHP email verification link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794959/easiest-way-for-php-email-verification-link).  Although that question and answer received several upvotes, you can also see in comments that some users found the question initially controversial, e.g. "SO isn't meant for building things for you; the community is for helping when you have a problem."

Since these "on-hold" or close votes are cast by experienced users who see a question, there is variability from human interpretation and preferences. Not all questions that one person thinks violate the guidelines are put on hold, and some questions are put on hold that one person will think should not be on hold.

As a check and balance, there is a "reopen" vote, which, as you have noticed, can lead to oscillation.

Comment: Thank you for this useful info. But the problem is that I have asked a question that I thought is not opinion based. I was checking whether there is any universally accepted method for email verification and the security issues and limitations of my method that I described in the question. I was not asking for which method to use, which site to check or something like that. I thought my question will get some straight forward answer.

Comment: Straight forward answer like, "No there is no such universally approved methods and your method have this and this limitation, this and this chances of security issues" or "Yes there is a universal method approved by [some authority name]" or something like that.

Comment: By asking this question, my profile on SO is on risk and getting this warning all the time
"Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?

Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity."

Comment: There are people who asked "which book to study", "is it okay to learn JAVA and PHP together" etc are still there asking questions like that and I am getting blocked from asking questions. Really wonderful. :P

Comment: The people who ask which book to study or whether to learn PHP before JS are getting snarky remarks and downvoted.  But Don't despair! It is worse than that: read [What is your best programmer joke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke).  Have a laugh, know that sort of question was once permitted or at least tolerated.  There are similar, more on topic questions about "What should everyone know about <Language>?" and "community-wiki" was an invention to deal with it and remove the ability to earn rep from such stuff.

Comment: To address your desire for a straightforward answer on the existence of a standard, you have to acknowledge that the people who answer the questions are only human.  You could probably have gotten that answered if asked directly and succinctly, without anything else distracting from it, but of course now you know the answer is "no".  Also, from the 152 previous answers you could probably read through numerous examples on different ways to do it and perhaps after a while, distinguish some good or common ways from bad ways to do it.  But that would be slower than just getting someone to answer.