# What can we do to promote/reward users that take the time to mentor newbies to SE?

Tags: discussion, mentoring

I was reading [What to Do When an Online Community Starts to Fail](http://blogs.hbr.org/2013/10/what-to-do-when-an-online-community-starts-to-fail/) and it got me thinking.

The article talks about studies done on mature online communities and what can be done to help keep them healthy. In their findings, the healthiest communities are ones where there is some turnover in the ranks, and existing users are very active in helping to engage and mentor new members.

> The challenge for community managers is to tie authority within a community to the mentoring of new members, whether formally, through changes in the way the platform calculates authority, or informally, by encouraging established members to lead through example in engaging new ones.

I think Stack Overflow has reached the point where it could be classified as a "mature online community", and I am already seeing the warning signs that we may not have a lot of incentive to help engage and mentor new members.

We are very quick to point out where newbies are wrong, or to downvote their contributions where it doesn't meet our standards, however the group of users that actually explains the problems to newbies and guides them into the correct approach is relatively small in comparison.

So this post is to ask

- What can we do to help promote a culture of engaging and guiding our new members in using Stack Exchange properly, that isn't going to be a huge drain on the community?

I'm curious to hear ideas that both use the existing set of tools available, or ones that would require some Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange development changes.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're talking about mentorship in *contribution to the site*, not mentoring/teaching *programming*, correct?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I was referring to menthorship for how to use Stack Exchange the right way, and not necessarily for users that help teach/mentor programming in specific tags.

Comment: I can see you are about to award a large bounty to a user that trolls one of the [tags] that I visit.  Never with an answer, always with "this sucks, you have to use the tool that I know" comments.  Is that the kind of "mentoring" you want to encourage?

Comment: I think you underestimate the sheer weight of the avalanche of newbies that now frequent Stack Overflow.  I also think you underestimate the lengths at which we already go to [mentor new users.](http://stackoverflow.com/help)  Given that the new users vastly outnumber the people here who can effectively mentor, do you honestly believe that the kind of hand-holding you describe would scale?

Comment: @Hans I have flagged a few of his comments for removal in the past too since I thought they were rude and/or offensive, and have even called him out on it a few times. But that doesn't stop the fact he has often gone out of his way to post long explanatory answers that not only answer the OP's original question, but also teaches them how they need to change their mindset to work with the technology so they don't need to post so many questions in the future. Overall, I think he's a good contributor to the tag, and want to publicly promote good actions while privately admonishing bad ones :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't actually think of a good solution, which is why I posted this question. I strongly believe that we need to do something, however I am not sure of what so am asking for ideas. All I have to go by is my own newbie experience using the sites, and the opinion of friends. And most of it is negative.

Comment: It would go a long way towards better understanding if some of your friends could come here and post an answer to the effect of *"Yes, I read the Help Center.  Yes, I lurked for awhile to see what kinds of questions are well-received, but still got rebuffed by your community when I tried to ask a question.  This is why I think it happens, and this is what I think you can do to fix it."*  [Sense of entitlement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258087) is a big part of the problem; we're all volunteers here.

Comment: Well, start at home, vote for answers that help every programmer.  Don't waste it on users that post rude and non-constructive comments, that's the very last thing a new user ever needs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did you read the article I linked? That is exactly the problem that I am trying to address... the existing crowd effectively shutting out newcomers with their attitude and expectations. I'd like to learn what we could do to improve the system so it encourages guidance and mentorship for newcomers. Btw, I've seen plenty of meta posts that already say something of that nature, and most only get downvoted and/or sarcastic comments. A brief look at the newest questions returned [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258006/302677) for example.

Comment: It's a pretty far distance between "Why did my post get downvoted" and "I read the Help Center. I lurked for awhile to see what kinds of questions are well-received, but still got rebuffed by your community when I tried to ask a question.  How can I improve further?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey To quote the question I linked: *I have read the terms and guidelines to ask question on stack overflow many times. I still can't find what is wrong with my question and how I broke the standard of asking question in stack overflow.*. The point is, that was an example. I see those kinds of meta posts frequently, and it took me almost no time at all to find an example post for you. I want ideas for how we can encourage and improve our guidance towards new Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow users. That is why I posted this question.

Comment: OK.  So what's wrong with the help he got there?

Comment: Maybe I'm totally off, but is there a problem with people who help new users not feeling rewarded for that behavior causing them to stop doing it? It seems to me that the bigger issue is preventing people from intentionally causing a negative experience for newer users. Could you explain why you think this is the issue that needs to be addressed a little more?

Comment: Ive been using SO for a while but for researching answers to my own questions, until recently.  I just started trolling around for questions that I could contribute answers to start "giving back".  Since doing that I see myself as a whole new member of the community.  One thing I have often wondered, is am I answering properly, commenting in a contributive way, or could I do something more or what not.  I of course have read the guidelines and all that, but it would be nice to get opinions from vets here to help me "Do it the right way."  Would that be the mentoring you are mentioning?

Comment: IMHO this should be aimed at the users who have enough rep to be beyond any of the gamification. Its about changing the attitude of the "us" who participate on meta, to take the time rather than just close or downvote. (of course, there's the flip side of all this, which gets dicussed at length in most meta posts)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier The problem is, that currently 90% of questions (or more, I'm optimistic here:)) would need "help". At least in the tags I participate in. We do not have and will never have enough people to do that. We are "forced" to simply downvote/close in cases we consider "unrecoverable". We leave comments when we see good intent and effort. Sometimes it helps, sometimes we are attacked :). Quite rarely, someone says "Thank you, now I understand what I did wrong!". That's enough reward, better than a badge.

Comment: @kapa we are not '"forced" to simply downvote/close'. That is a choice we all make, when we decide we would rather not get involved (which is fine, cos I'm not a professional StackOverflower... I pretend I have a life outside of this). But I don't see how gamifying this process will help - many of us who could be mentoring are beyond caring about rep in that way.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier That is why I wrote "forced", not forced. Garbage should not be left in the house, so we downvote/close. This is already mentoring, btw.

Comment: @kapa fair 'nuff

Comment: @BenVoigt What's wrong with mentoring *both*? If nothing else, this is a service community, and it seems to me we should trip over each other in pursuit of serving those who need it - both in how to use the site, and as necessary, the breadth of programming as well. It makes everyone smarter, and that makes the site all the better for it.

Comment: I don't know the new user process/experience. For all too many it seems to be "post, downvoted/closed, post, downvoted/closed, post, downvoted/closed, question ban, :tableflip: disgruntled meta question etc." How many warnings does "that" type of user get? Should it be more like: "post, downvoted forced to sit an automated hand-holdy tutorial?" I don't know what would work as a tutorial - pseudo review queue "do you really think this question makes any sense?"? - whatever it is it should aim to prevent users taking no action before becoming "a problem".

Comment: @DavidW: If you meet a new programmer needing mentoring and you want to provide that, great.  Find a communication channel outside SO and mentor your heart out.  But the main site is not for discussion, hand-holding, or following other users' progress.  The only place here where mentoring on programming principles could be performed without breaking a dozen rules is chat.

Comment: I visited StackOverflow in search of answers for years before creating an account here. Absolutely nothing wrong with the way the community reacts to new users. If they don't think it's necessary to learn the rules of the site they are dumping their questions on, they do not deserve the handholding some seem to advocate. The help pages and automatic search for duplicates while posting are right in their faces and they CHOOSE to ignore it, this is not SO's fault or concern.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand and respect your position, but I yet firmly disagree. If we decide to become a social forum that helps only the ones those we 'deign' to help, then we've lost our way. We become a site where we take turns telling each other how wonderful we are, while the folks we're here to help decide not to bother getting slammed for asking 'you should know better' questions. At one point, especially in the pre-Internet era, we were *all* there, needing help from someone who knew better.

Comment: @DavidW We all need help sometimes, but no help is useful without your own hard efforts. Just a waste of time.

Comment: @David We have decided *not* to become a 'social forum'. Of course, as you know, Stack Overflow is not like a traditional online forum; we are a Q&A site. But I recognize there are other definitions of the word "forum", so I'll grant that you meant to imply one of those meanings. Either way, there is nothing *social* about it. We try to minimize social interaction to the extent possible. Meta is somewhat of an exception; here we allow subjective discussion. That's not the case on the main site. It is not about the users. The goal should be to treat everyone *equally*. SO is not a social club.

Comment: And along those lines, I take issue with this entire question. We should not be "mentoring" anyone. That implies a focus on *people*, which is entirely misplaced. When I'm answering a question or evaluating an answer, the user is irrelevant. It doesn't matter if they are a new user or not. That shouldn't even be something one pays attention to, because it opens the door for a whole host of inappropriate behaviors. That's the reason we establish guidelines, meant to apply universally. I'm not against leaving helpful comments; I do plenty of that. But I'm against mentoring. That isn't Q&A.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with your first comment, but not the 2nd one. Wikipedia is definitely not a social site, but see how the number of contributors and quality of contributions has fallen? The point is not to mentor people on the site, but to mentor them in how to use the site properly. This site is *run by the community*, which means no matter what there will always need to be some kind of social interactions, and mentoring and guidance of new users into how to use the site properly is very important for the site's continued health and growth.

Comment: @CodyGray Understand your position, there, Cody, but it isn't up to us to decide what kind of forum we are. That's like an egg deciding it wants to be a banana. We *are* a social form regardless of whether we like it. If we truly are this worried about "improper behavior" and "reference quality" content, then we should *immediately* shut down the ability for ad-hoc question posting and make *all* submissions moderated. I, personally, don't like the arrogant direction SO is taking toward people seeking help, turning it into a punitive site because the rest of us are just too smart for the room

Comment: Having standards is a far cry from being punitive. An egg can't decide anything, that's a ridiculous example. It is certainly up to us to decide what type of site we want to be. Some people may abuse Stack Overflow as a social forum, but that doesn't mean it is something we should start striving for or even embracing. People use our chat rooms for matchmaking, too. Are you in favor of that? Rachel, I have not seen any decrease in the quality of contributions to Wikipedia. If anything, it has gotten nothing but better over the last few years—a very different trajectory than I see on SO.

Comment: One of the problems is that good behavior today is different then what it was in the early days.  For example, there were plenty of questions that were of the type - What library should I use to [. . .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f).  So if you are a new user and you start typing in a question title What Python Library Should I use to . . . the list of possible matches are questions with lots of rep attached to them and with answers.  T

Comment: If I were a new user I would conclude that this is valid behavior.  So I continue to post my question.  How do you mentor someone in these circumstances?  The application of the rules is going to appear to be inconsistent.  I think rep should be lost if you downvote a question from a first timer without first adding a comment about why the question is inappropriate.  I have encouraged people to close their question but I think I try to point them in the right direction first.  I resist downvoting a question from a naive user because I can generally find models of their question with good rep

Comment: "I, personally, don't like the arrogant direction SO is taking toward people seeking help, turning it into a punitive site because the rest of us are just too smart for the room".....I really feel this.Now I know I' am not the only one

Comment: I wish you would look at some of my more recent questions on meta - particularly https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378837/building-an-engineering-community?noredirect=1#comment661928_378837 You want to read vogl's book on community first. I'd love to talk more about making an actual community.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm a noob on to SE (and to lesser extent, to programming) and what I appreciated was people commenting on my questions telling me how to improve them. If I'm honest, I would have liked a few more of those kind of comments.

A possibility there could be to indicate that a question is one of the first 3 questions of a user and rewarding point or a badge for good comment (not answers) on that question. The same could go for bad questions, much like the Reversal badge Mico mentions.

I also think that [peer reviewing questions of newbies and bad users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them) and [auto-commenting close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256808/auto-comment-close-votes-for-all-close-reasons) could help get new users get feedback on the way they are asking questions. I especially like the former, because it doesn't just focus on bad users, but also on rather unremarkable users that seem to slip through the net.

Comment: One issue with the *first 3 questions of a user* is the issue of bad people asking numerous bad questions, getting their accounts locked and then starting the whole process all over again with another account.

Comment: Hand holding in the comments should be frowned upon I suppose, A good comment improves the question, rather than provide an answer. We should rate comments according to that criterium (easier said than done of course). If people leave those kind of good comments for questions by noobs, the lazy ones will be turned off and the enthusiastic ones will learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: @Liam, upvoted comments on answers by users who just started answering could of course also be rewarded.

Comment: @overactor Not a good idea, unconstructive/offensive comments under hopeless questions tend to be upvoted :).

Comment: Yes, agree, the amount of times I've seen words to the effect of *"P*** off noob"* with 5 upvotes. This type of comment shouldbn't be rewarded

Comment: @kapa What if we require the comment to also be upvoted by the OP? That would imply that it was a good comment (many upvotes) and the OP took something from it (OP upvoted).

Comment: @overactor I'd say the OP is not really qualified to decide that most of the time. Also, the content of the comment matters, and computers cannot decide that. You should not get a badge for a "You should not have closed this, stupid close-warriors! SO is dying!" comment (possibly from a highrep user), which the OP and some others might upvote.

Comment: @kapa, I see your point, though I do think that, if anything, the OP is qualified to decide if he got something from the message. But you're probably right, teh way the comments work at the moment, they are not suited for rating to count.

Answer (score 45):

It looks to me like we are already doing that, at least for the folks that are
open to constructive criticism. Case in point:

[Why is my question getting close votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258006)

1. User posts question on Meta, genuinely asking for advice.
2. User gets detailed feedback in comments.
3. User takes feedback and responds constructively.
4. ?
5. Profit!

Compare with:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/24001763

1. User post clearly off-topic question.
2. User is notified in comments that question is off-topic.
3. User openly flouts the rules and brags about it.
4. Complaint posted on meta
5. Moderator steps in to stop the bloodletting.
6. Everyone is sad.

Who had control over the situation? The user, in both cases.

---

I do not think we have a mandate to provide personal, one on one training to
every new user who trips over one of the community’s cultural norms. All of the
information that a new user needs to know to use Stack Overflow
productively is already available to him. There are built-in mechanisms to allow
people mistakes on their first few questions, and an entire site devoted to
getting feedback. The new users willing to learn from those mistakes usually do
fine on subsequent questions.

In short, I do not think the problem is mentoring. Hand-holding is exactly what
the Help Vampire expects; doing more of it only encourages more Help Vampirism.

Comment: I'm asking for ideas on how we can encourage and mentor new users to SE in a way that doesn't cause a huge drain on the community. Asking every user to post a question on meta is not a good solution, as it doesn't scale with Stack Overflows userbase size and is not very intuitive to the user. Also, I would not consider downvoting people who come to meta asking for help to be "encouraging and mentoring new members".

Comment: How do you propose to deal with the folks that don't want to be mentored?

Comment: You do realize I am talking about engaging/mentoring new members to Stack Exchange's network and Q&A format right? To keep Stack Exchange with a healthy userbase of members that can contribute to running the site without abusing their powers and driving contributors away? And am not referring specifically to engaging/mentoring new programmers that are seeking answers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: When a person gets rebuffed on Stack Overflow, and does not improve, it is *their* fault, not ours.  Until you understand that, you'll always wonder why the SO community is so mean, and why there are *real consequences* for not affording the community the smallest measure of respect by at least taking a few moments to find out what the community is all about, and how to meaningfully engage with that community.

Comment: Any effort that does not place that responsibility *squarely on the new users' shoulders* is doomed to fail.  We're simply vastly outnumbered, and everything that a new user needs to know to succeed on Stack Overflow is already readily available to them.

Comment: By the way, are you on the right site?  If you want this to be a network-wide question, you need to be asking it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The fundamental issue here is that the "we will not reconsider if our policy is the correct one" issue highlighted Robert's example number 2 is precisely the kind of heavy-handedness that begs for **equally hostile** responses.  In the eyes of any ordinary person the poster has asked a decent question, and slamming the door as rudely as was done is **not** likely to encourage them to come around to your way of thinking, but rather only increase their impression that SO is a difficult and unfriendly place.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: That's not what is being highlighted in example 2.  What's being highlighted there is the "I'll do what I want, when I want, and I don't care what your rules are" attitude of the poster.  Nobody who leave Stack Overflow with the impression that it is an unfriendly place ever considers the possibility that it is *the way that they are approaching the community* that is the cause of that unfriendliness.  Those folks are not open to a "mentoring" approach; if they were, they would submit to mentoring, become good Stackizens, and everyone would live happily ever after.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - ultimately, there are more of *them* than there are of you.  You might get rid of that user, but there will be another tomorrow who has a different view than you of what an appropriate question is, and another the day after that.  You can fight - or maybe someday you'll be open to adapting.  Right now, it doesn't look like you are any more open to *learning from them* than they are to learning from you.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In what way do you propose that we adapt?  Capitulate?  Surrender to the masses?  Let anarchy prevail?  If you have a constructive suggestion that doesn't involve lowering our standards, the answer box is waiting for you below.

Comment: Adapt to the needs of the wider community; **while preserving the needs** of users such as yourself by substantially (though not completely) substituting *per-user viewing filters* in place of one-size-fits-all global moderation.

Comment: Yay another statement by you stating everything I say is just a thinly veiled attempt to destroy the site... I wish you'd stop it. I read the article which was linked to me by Ed in SO's latest blog post, and was thinking *hey this sounds like something SO could use to improve the health of their community*, so was trying to think of ways to improve this. But I couldn't think of any, so posted a question to ask others to help me. And as always, you come around and accuse me of having some nefarious motive. This is exactly the sort of attitude which leads me to leave the site needs to change.

Comment: @Rachel: I apologize.  I've removed the paragraph you've reference from my answer, but ultimately this is a "world-view" problem.  Your world view simply differs from mine, that's all.  It always has.  This article is actually a better one than the one you were referred to: http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html

Comment: @Rachel: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6677

Comment: @Rachel: Seriously though, it would *really* help the Stack Exchange community to get feedback about why the Help Center articles don't seem to help people ask questions the right way.  If the articles are the problem, then perhaps we can fix them.

Comment: Without creating a new account and deliberately being a derp - is it possible to walk through the new-user experience? I think new users don't read the help because however in-your-face the messages are they simply aren't effective; they don't stand _directly_ in your way to keep on doing what you did before. For example [I've seen the question-ban warning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232104/243527) - while that case was in error I didn't have any other warning that on MSE my account wasn't in good standing, and the warning didn't prevent me doing exactly what I intended to do.

Comment: " at least for the folks that are open to constructive criticism" that seems to be the core of the issue

Comment: Help vampires are looking for fish.  The question here is how to teach them to fish instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What if it's the help center itself that's the problem?  Let's face it, people with time to RTFM do not come to Stack Exchange - they go read the manual and figure out what to do that way.  The only reason to come to Stack Exchange is to quickly find a way to solve one's immediate problem, and the more manuals they have to read, the less attractive the site is.

Comment: @WarrenDew I read manuals *and* Stack Overflow. I don't ask SO questions though, not because I'm so awesome, but because I find the answers here already. So the reason to come here is not and **should not be** to quickly ask and quickly receive some answer, there are other sites for that. If this site becomes less attractive to these people, well, it is a great thing! Again, we do not want and need everyone here. Help vampires already learnt to fish. They fish here, and they get what they want. Why change?

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer, as it's basically the wrong way round, and is _sort of_ stick-head-in-sand. It's not that I'm oblivious to the onslaught of poor questions, somehow immune to being jaded by woefully poor questions, don't feel that giving constructive feedback is "mentoring" or feel that the help section doesn't describe what users should do - the problem is they _aren't_ reading/actioning that information and therefore the problem is getting new users to do so, systematically. Any "we're already doing everything we can" is missing the point of the question as asked.

Answer (score 44):

### We are not here to feed people

Stack Overflow is not here to teach everyone programming. Now, this might sound elitist. But we should not be afraid of this. This is not Facebook. We do not want everyone to become a member. Professional and enthusiast programmers should enter. Others stay out. Not because we do not like them! This is what some people should understand. I really love my wife, my parents, etc., but I do not tell them to come to Stack Overflow.

### We are already giving enough help to newbies

I do not see a huge problem with this (of course there can be edge cases, as always). Those who want to get better get the help. We have a detailed help section and we have meta. When newbies ask in comments for help/clarification showing the desire of improving themselves (not "xplain the downvote assclowns!!1!"), they receive their helpful response.

**We cannot help those who do not want to help themselves.** We should not even try, because we are programmers, and we do not waste resources.

### Mentoring

Downvoting is mentoring. "Closing" is mentoring. Comments that might look harsh (because they hurt your ego) are nothing but mentoring. You need to commit mistakes and those mistakes need to earn you their (in most cases "negative") consequences in order to learn. On a site for programmers you would expect to have intelligent people who will understand this.

---

Let me give a personal example. At the time I found SO, looking at the main page, I got the impression this is *a site full of pros*. I did not even register for a year. I felt I am not good enough yet and would just unnecessarily disturb them (also I already found the answers to most of my questions). I was in read-only mode. Saw a lot of downvoting, closing, strict comments (all the stuff some people call "negative" for some reason) and that **helped** me a lot. Gave me motivation to learn how to solve problems myself. When I registered, also received my share of "negativity" and that **helped** even more over time.

**Note:** If I look at the site from the "outside" now, things changed. The impression I get on the main page is *a site full of low quality questions*. We got a horde of people asking questions who did not even look at a basic tutorial about the topic, did not even try to solve the problem themselves. If I'd be a newbie now, I guess I would register instantly and ask my stupid questions :).

Comment: The OP: "What can we do to help promote a culture of engaging and guiding our new members in using Stack Exchange properly, that isn't going to be a huge drain on the community?" You did not answer that question. On one hand you say we already do enough, but on the other your post ends up with the standard Meta chorus about how great things USED to be here. Can't really have it both ways.

Comment: @neuronet The question was *What can we do to help promote a culture of engaging and guiding our new members in using Stack Exchange properly, that isn't going to be a huge drain on the community?*, as far as I understood. But even if we look at your questions, I answered both. People deserve to be mentored, it is already done, and it helps. Most of them resist mentoring though, unfortunately.

Comment: @neuronet To your edit to your comment: maybe you don't understand what I'm saying. We do enough in mentoring new users. I do not mention what we should improve in other areas, because that is not what this question is about - we have really serious problems though, but not with mentoring. The "standard meta chorus" part was about the positive effects of "negativity" and an example about how mentoring worked with me not requiring *specific* effort and hand-holding from seniors. I am happy to explain it more thoroughly if you have questions.

Comment: I completely agree with the last part. If you look at the homepage you get the feeling you can ask anything and get an answer. Perhaps we should change the homepage to only allow questions with atleast a +2 score and a positive scoring answer. That way the homepage only shows what we want and perhaps it scares people into thinking first

Comment: My first days on SO/SE were full of criticism. I wouldn't say they were harsh, more like they were strict guidance. Most of the people here get absolute brutal feedback... from their compiler that crashes their program for little given reason. Any kind of help is welcome, which is what SO is for. But there should be just enough disincentive to keep people from posting as soon as they come across a simple bug. Points and harsh comments are, IMO, not enough of a disincentive.

Comment: "We are already giving enough help to newbies" - I agree with that, I was a newbie few months ago and got a lot of feedback from [Andrew Barber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) which really helped. It's really up to an individual how he/she takes the feedbacks

Answer (score 17):

Do new users see that their posts went into the First Posts Review Queue, and what the outcome was?

I was reading [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258085/what-can-we-do-to-promote-reward-users-that-take-the-time-to-mentor-newbies-to-s?noredirect=1#comment34695_258085) and realizing I had the exact same trepidation when I first started asking/answering. I didn't know if I was doing it right, and wished someone could tell me if what I was doing was OK or if I needed improvement, and if so what I could improve on.

**We should show new users that their posts were in the First Posts Review Queue and what the result was.**

> Since you are a new user, your post was peer-reviewed by other users and the feedback was xyz.

Furthermore, I think that if someone is going through the First Posts Review Queue, they should be *required* to leave some kind of textual feedback for the person.

To help reviewers, it would be nice if there were some canned responses such as that users could check off, with links to the relevant meta docs if applicable, such as

- Could be improved with explanation to go with code.
- Could be improved with some sample code.
- Answers should be able to stand on their own, and should not be nothing more than a link.
- 3rd party links are OK, as long as they also explain why and how it answers the question.
- Post looks fine.

Or freeform text entry if the user wishes to provide a custom reason why the answer is not acceptable.

Canned responses could be different per site depending on the rules too.

If someone is taking the time to go through the First Posts queue, I don't think it's uncalled for to ask them to leave some kind of textual feedback beyond an up/down vote to help guide newbies in what they're doing right or wrong.

Afterall, isn't that one of the goals of the First Posts review queue? To educate users that are new to the site, and not merely to punish them or stamp on their contributions.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a sandpit new users can (forced?) use to ask a question on before being able to ask a question on SO - A sandpit where everything is automated (and in reality just js). I imagine a tutorial which wouldn't let you submit a question until 1) it contains code 2) the code is formatted 3) contains some formatting would go a long way to reducing the necessity to comment those things to new users.

Comment: Even if the person is a newbie, there are many posts that just don't observe the standards of modern, human, professional communications. I have answered many questions for people who do not even validate their account.  It's still set as "user123421312", they never confirmed the initial discussions that opened up, or they didn't bother to return to confirm if the answer helped... this is an outrage and an insult to know such disrespect for the people who attempt to answer.

Comment: If you'd make commenting required in the First Posts queue, it is absolutely necessary to have automated comments. We have too many robo-reviewers who would just add 15 random characters and click "I'm Done".

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr

- Develop a method to flag the well posed and answered versions of each question in the style of a peer-reviewed 'Featured Q&A'

It is interesting to note that the charitable & tolerant attitudes expressed at [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) are from '09, the 'early life' of SO. I doubt they would pass as commonly accepted today. Is that a good thing?

Since programming languages are closed, logically consistent systems, the number of meaningful unique questions about aspects of programming is finite. Hence, a mature community transitions from being all about content creation (eg. Wikipedia circa 2008) to being more focussed on organisation, quality and curatorship (Wikipedia circa 2014).

There is still room for the occassional answering of a truly brilliant, novel and/or well posed question and those will be answered enthusiastically by the experts.

This is not the sign of the start of a community 'failing', merely a coming of age. The community inevitably becomes more closed, but that is not necessarily a bad thing.

'Featured Q/A's will be easily identifiable go-to page hits. Since the proportion of duplicate questions will increase over time, also lower the bar to redirect & close. If the asker feels their question was not answered by the redirect, they will be more specific when asking next time.

Easy to find good answers, higher quality questions and easier curatorship.

Comment: So in other words, accept duplicate questions as a way of life and a byproduct of SO's size, and turn efforts toward creating peer-reviewed canonical answers?

Comment: *"the number of meaningful unique questions about aspects of programming is finite"* ... never before have I seen a more incorrect comment about programming.  Perhaps more than **any** other field right now, programming is constantly changing.  New languages, new APIs, new use cases, better hardware to enable things that used to be impossible.  The set of reasonable questions isn't even remotely finite.  This site needs to embrace a continuing influx of new content (for the foreseeable future), and get out of this mode where the "establishment" thinks that censorship makes it better.

Answer (score -2):

```
What can we do to help promote a culture of engaging and guiding our new members
in using Stack Exchange properly, that isn't going to be a huge drain on the
community?
```

It should just become aspired behavior that questions that are not closed and not upvoted, i.e. the valid but not very useful questions, get a comment or two how to improve their quality. This is already the case in a significant amount of cases but also quite often not.

Of course it's voluntary and if you don't want, don't do anything. But if we can agree that one or two comments would be nice for low level but valid questions, then this is the right direction. If just enough people follow the advice displayed after a downvote, everything will be okay.

I wouldn't introduce any element of gamification for it, although it might actually increase the motivation, but such things are difficult to track. The only possibility might be a badge for upvoted comments on questions that have no answer.

Comment: " for low level but valid questions" I would say we already do this. All the other crap that gets close&downvoted into oblivion I would consider invalid questions here.

Answer (score -5):

**Could we be clearer about what people are signing up to at the start?**

I noticed recently that on the "Sign Up" page for Stack Overflow that there is just that - a sign up input. No other information.

It appears to be rather assumed that you will know what Stack Overflow is all about and what it is for.

Sure there is a "tour" link in the bottom left corner, but it is by no means obligatory to use it, and it is clearly possible to sign up and post without reading a single thing. This would surely be the most effective point at which to educate new users and even filter the new arrivals.

Would it be a good idea, perhaps, to take people who want to sign up through "a little walk around" to show them what they are signing up to and what they should expect/what will be expected of them before they can put email and password to browser?

A comment on another question raised the issue that many new people see the Stack Exchange as a kind of forum for solving their immediate and often highly frustrating problems, in line with many tech support sites, rather than something in the perhaps more hallowed Wiki style of site - a repository for quality information with a broader application.

Though I understand the frustration of those longer-standing members for whom the new wave of OP takes too much of a forum style approach, I am often shocked at how brutally some new members are treated and have recently answered a number of questions where, with a bit of thought, you could work out through the poor English, what the questioner was trying to achieve, though there were many aggressive and impatient comments or votes to close what where actually quite interesting things.

Perhaps we might be less dismissive of poorly phrased questions where the limitation is in the language skill rather than the idea the OP is trying to express.

I wonder, also if there is a case for a Stack Newbies - where those who would like to help new or inexperienced programmers can work and where newbies might even earn "credits" towards joining SO, if SO is to be kept as an exclusive "high level programmers' club".

Possibly there might also be a case for creating a "Stack Snippets" - where those who want an answer to "I want to do xyz" or "can you fix my code?" could get answers from those who enjoy that kind of interaction without them upsetting those who want a more Wiki level of activity.

Either way we would be encouraging new coders and not being aggressive towards them. As it is most new posters already seem very polite and deferential - even fearful - to post. as far as I have seen, though there are always exceptions to any rule.

The devolution you mention in your article might not be such a bad thing, and, if we have somewhere for them to be encouraged to go, perhaps those whose questions are seen by the community as not welcome, could be encouraged to transfer their activities, away from SO, to the more appropriate site? That way they could be encouraged by those who were happy and willing rather than be a burden on those who did not see writing code and teaching as their role.

Perhaps that would then help to return the state of StackOverflow to where it started, where the reward in itself was to share expertise at a certain level, where it would be valued and respected, the loss of which, it appears is what is mostly lamented as having been lost over time.

Comment: Did you fix the questions too? If so, good. If not, let's hope (against expectations) that the respective questions get pruned soon anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator I did try but my edit got first accepted, then rejected, so gave up.

Comment: Well, you have three suggested edits, all rejected. The first one certainly deservedly so, adding that comment to the OP's code seems unjustifiable. The third is a complete rewrite, and I'm not too sure you aren't completely changing the question. The middle one now, that rejection is unfortunate. Still, you should have removed the fluff while you were at it, though missing that does not justify the rejection. I fear the question is still too broad afterwards, but anyway I have applied your suggestion.

Comment: @Deduplicator. Thanks for those thoughts - very much in the spirit of the question and most helpful. I will perhaps have another go at an edit in the future. I think the first one was accidental, in that I had meant to add it to my own answer. The editing interface takes a bit of learning!

Comment: Just a thought about the forced tour suggestion on signup - typically when I sign up for a site it's because I want to take an action immediately, such as posting a question/answer/comment or voting. If I encounter a tutorial on signup, I'm likely to just skip through it so I can get back to what I was first doing. I would personally prefer something along Reddit's lines of a very noticable message of "Before posting, be sure to read the Rules" link that goes a very short concise bullet-pointed list of rules that all users should know before posting.

Comment: @Rachel Yes it is a difficult one and not helped by the contradictory pressures of keeping up programming standards versus getting lots of people sat in front of the advertising in SO. It seems that on the one hand, as in many exclusive clubs, there would almost be a case for having to be sponsored by another member to join, or even pass some kind of programming test to establish a baseline of understanding of what the OP will be asking about. Perhaps, if we want to maintain the "standard" we need to make it harder, but then we would sacrifice volume of membership - "quality" versus quantity.

Answer (score -6):

Although I agree with [Kapa's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258173/2886003), the question is:

> What can we do to help promote a culture of engaging and guiding our new members in using Stack Exchange properly, that isn't going to be a huge drain on the community?

So I will post some kind of things that can be done to promote more than it is already.

There are two ways of promoting an action on Stack Overflow, points or badges. Points are useful for new users who want to reach some privileges. Badges are(n't) good for expert site users [Why?]. Therefore I would encourage the use of badges to promote this culture as they also don't suppose a big drain to the community.

To guide it is needed to communicate, so mainly my ideas are based on evaluating the communication between members. I know that this is not a forum or a social place, but we can measure and use the tools we already have.

**Ideas**:

- A (bronze) badge for experienced users (2k) who had (at least) one
  chat with a user under 100 points which and reaches 1k of points.
- A (silver) badge for experienced users who posted 500 links to a help page in a new user first question or answer.
- A (gold) badge for experienced user that had 10 short conversations
  under (comments a new user (<100) question and the question was
  reopened.

Answer (score -11):

Don't we have  ["Reversal Badge"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) to address this concern? At least it encourages to answer less popular questions and topics.

Comment: At least this badge aims for not underestimating down voted questions and thus not letting the user with bad mood and with no solution. Of course direct feedback and mentoring support is not calculated, although often implicitly needed to be able to do this achievement.

Comment: Evidently a badge is not enough.  Ultimately, rep is the currency here, not badges.

Answer (score -14):

My suggestion would be to create a badge for answering questions for users with low rep. This is subtly different to the reversal badge which rewards good answers to bad questions because it encourages answers to good (but inexperienced) users.

If you wanted to expand this the badges could be for commenting/editing/answering... helping the new user to create a better question rather than simply going and answering trivial questions.

Comment: Could this be misused? [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and generally providing answers to questions that already have a duplicate rather than simply flagging it as such.

Comment: @Liam very likely - it probably needs some vote threshold too