# Scrounger users that never validates good answers and never upvote

Tags: discussion

I am a young active user here at Stack Overflow and very new here at Meta *(I am French-Mexican, so please excuse my poor english)*.

I have noticed one user taking benefits egoistically from other users by just asking questions and never validating the good answers and never upvoting. This user also use the comment feature at the minimal state to get the right information when is convenient for him, and sometimes never answer when is not…

I have noticed that by going on his profile and reviewing all the questions.

When you take time by searching, thinking, writing and commenting answers, if your answer is convenient and you get nothing (validating and upvoting is similar to "thanks" on Stack Overflow), it leaves me a bitter taste in the mouth…

What to do in this case? Is that kind of attitude convenient?

***(EDIT)***
It seems that this question is a duplicate of [Help Vampires](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258087/what-should-we-do-about-users-who-are-proud-to-be-help-vampires). Do i delete it or someone will close-it?

Comment: What kind of question are they asking? Are they useful for others? If so, others will surely vote over time.

Comment: Sometimes yes sometimes not. They are always useful for them :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I see this as a scenario in which the user asks a question but gets their answer and doesn't upvote or accept anyone else's, which isn't necessarily the same as flagrantly breaking the rules just to get an answer.

Comment: Occasionally, you can bump into users that genuinely don't know how accepting answers works. You can usually spot that when they leave thank you comments under answers but have no single accepted answer for their questions. In that case I politely refer them to [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and in most cases they do accept answer. I do that for other people's questions and not just for my own, and if there are more then single answer posted I try to be as neutral as I can.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by defining a few things:

- You're free to use your votes as you see fit.  This also includes accepting answers.  This freedom also extends to *abstaining* on a vote.
- A "good" answer is a subjective, elusive beast which exists not necessarily in the count of votes on an answer, but also on its lasting impact and clarity.

Now, to the main point:  there's really nothing *wrong* with this from a rules standpoint, considering that there's no rule that mandates that a user votes in any direction.  That said, be very careful on how you react to their questions in the future, since I don't want to turn you into a vigilante:

- If anyone asks a question that is unclear, not well researched, or off-topic, don't hesitate to downvote and vote to close (in the case of unclear/off-topic).
- Don't go through this person's questions and vote on them.  That will be seen by the system as serial voting, and you could be punished for that.
- **Don't let this get to you.** It happens, and there's really not much point in getting worked up in it.

Comment: I agree totally. But i don't like this kind of user… My action against him: i will never answer again. That is the only thing that i can do.

Answer (score 4):

This is discouraging, but it may happen that the type of user you describe contributes by asking good questions that will help others in the future.

I would save my wrath and indignation for users who self-delete their Questions as soon as a pertinent but not yet up-voted Answer appears.  Such a behavior is bilking the Community of good will, by selfishly removing the possibility of content that will help others in the future.